# State of constant motion

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, special-relativity, nuclear-physics

Why does an object remains in its state of constant motion if there are no forces acting on that object?

My understanding is that all the energy of the motion will be kept inside and a change in the speed needs a change in the amount of the energy stored by that object. But how is that energy stored in a form of speed?
Does anything changes inside the object's structure if it is moving?

Answer (score 1):

the main reason is that the space is uniform, and that there is nor absolute reference point in the universe.

basically, what appears to be moving at constant speed to you, will be moving at a different constant speed or even not moving at all to another observer who is moving at constant speed in reference to you. since your point of view is not any better than his, then who said that the object is moving at all? it might as well be staying in the same place.

Comment: I agree with you on this, but my question is more about the object itself. How does it stores the motion energy? I mean, we could be travelling at the speed of light right now (or very close to it) relative to something and not even knowing it. Is it really no reference to changes of the object structure?

Comment: @user43647, motion is not a *property* of an object, motion is a relationship between two objects, i.e., two objects can be in motion *relative* to each other but neither can be said to be *absolutely* moving.

Comment: like @AlfredCentauri pointed out: how do you _know_ that what you _think_ is moving is _actually_ moving? if i'm moving at the speed with the object, i'll claim that it's not moving at all. who's right?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri this is probably overcomplicating things for the level of this question, but I'd argue that massless particles *are* absolutely moving, since every observer measures the same velocity.

Comment: @Kyle, an invariant speed is not the same as absolute motion.  The existence of absolute motion implies the existence of an absolute *rest* frame of reference to which absolutely moving objects are moving with respect to.  However, the existence of an invariant speed does not imply the existence of an absolute rest frame of reference but, rather, the *lack* of a reference frame for massless objects.

Comment: I will add a comment related to relativistic Doppler Effect. From what I understand from SR, time is expanding for the object that moves relative to the observer. That means that emission lines are changed when looking from the observer but not proportional to v/c. Does that mean that the probability of electron distribution around nucleus changes with speed?

Comment: @user43647, if you want to discuss atomic physics, it's better done in a new question. increasing the scope of this question is not a good idea. it'll discourage people from answering your questions in future.

Answer (score 0):

What is force? It is the transfer of momentum with respect to time. Momentum is the product of mass of a body, and it relative velocity with respect to something. If we imagine, for once, our world made up of tiny uniform particles, then we can take the mass of one particle as one unit mass. This simplifies the situation, as the momentum, *'mass x velocity'* becomes, *velocity x 1 = velocity*. So, when two such particles collide, they exert force on each other. 
Or, literally, the faster particle loses a bit of its velocity and the slower particle gains the same with respect to time.

You are asking- *" why does an object remains in a state of constant motion if no force acts on it".*

This question is same as asking *" Why does a unit mass particle has a constant velocity if it is not gaining some velocity."*

For some reason, relative motion of a particle in space is a conserved constant. A particle does not gains velocity until some other particle loses the same amount of it. This is the same as the fact that a shopkeeper gains money if some customer loses the same amount of money in his shop.

(Yes, of course money gets *lost* sometime, or damaged, with a net lose to humanity, but in the universe at least, it is not easy to lose your momentum with nobody gaining the same amount, instantly!)